# difference between these two regular expression

Tags: python, regex, expression

could somebody explain the difference between these two Regular Expression:

```
re.search('^[abcd]z$', noun)
```

and

```
re.search('[^abcd]z$', noun)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `^` can either [be a position anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) or [negate a character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'^[abcd]z$'` must match starting at the beginning of the string.

`'[^abcd]z$` matches anything with is *not* in the character class `[abcd]`, followed by a `z`.

As you can see, the `^` has vastly different meanings inside and outside of the brackets. Outside the brackets, `^` matches the start of the string, while if `^` is the first character inside brackets, it indicates a complementing set.

---

This matches, since `'dz'` starts with a character in `[abcd]`.

```
In [102]: re.search('^[abcd]z', 'dz')
Out[102]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0xa12b480>
```

This does not match since `[^abcd]` matches anything but `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`.

```
In [103]: re.search('[^abcd]z', 'dz')
```

While this does match since `e` is not in `[abcd]`.

```
In [104]: re.search('[^abcd]z', 'ez')
Out[104]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0xa12b3a0>
```

---

Per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `'^'`:
>       (Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline.
>
> `'[]'`:
>   Characters that are not within a range can be matched by complementing
>   the set. If the first character of the set is '^', all the characters
>   that are not in the set will be matched. For example, [^5] will match
>   any character except '5', and [^^] will match any character except
>   '^'. ^ has no special meaning if it’s not the first character in the
>   set.